# How to subtract previous row from current row in a pandas dataframe to create a new column restarting the process with each name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns in which the first column is a categorical variable with a person name, the second column is the date and the third column are the cumulative ocurrences of a problem. I would like to generate a new column with the ocurrences by day per person.

```
**Name     Date          Cumulative**

John     01-01-2020    0
John     02-01-2020    5
John     03-01-2020    10
John     04-01-2020    12
Peter    01-01-2020    0
Peter    02-01-2020    3
Peter    03-01-2020    7
Peter    04-01-2020    10
James    01-01-2020    0
James    02-01-2020    10
James    03-01-2020    14
James    04-01-2020    18
Kirk     01-01-2020    0
Kirk     02-01-2020    12
Kirk     03-01-2020    12
Kirk     04-01-2020    15
Rob      01-01-2020    0
Rob      02-01-2020    11
Rob      03-01-2020    18
Rob      04-01-2020    23
```

If I use df['By Day'] = df.Cumulative.diff() the result is good but in the first ocurrence of each person it will give me the negative number instead of 0 (because it subtracts the previous number to the 0). It would give me as follows:

```
Name     Date          Cumulative  By Day

John     01-01-2020    0           0
John     01-02-2020    0           0
John     03-01-2020    5           5
John     04-01-2020    10          5
John     05-01-2020    12          2
Peter    01-01-2020    0           -12
Peter    02-01-2020    0           0
Peter    03-01-2020    3           3
Peter    04-01-2020    7           4
Peter    04-01-2020    10          3
James    01-01-2020    0           -10
James    02-01-2020    0           0
James    03-01-2020    10          10
James    04-01-2020    14          4
James    04-01-2020    18          4 
Kirk     01-01-2020    0           -18
Kirk     02-01-2020    0           0
Kirk     03-01-2020    12          12
Kirk     04-01-2020    15          3
Kirk     04-01-2020    19          4
Rob      01-01-2020    5           -14
Rob      02-01-2020    11          6
Rob      03-01-2020    18          7
Rob      04-01-2020    23          5
Rob      04-01-2020    27          4
```

I would like to do the difference by each name so that it starts from 0 every time the person is not the same. I've thought about using an iteration by name but it will do it 5 times for each entry. For example I would want, for Rob, 0 6 7 5 4 instead of starting with -14 (the previous 19 from Kirk -5 from Rob's first entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first use `groupby` function on the `Name` column to apply the `diff` function separately over every person. Then you can use `fillna(0)` to replace `NaN` values (which will exist in the first row of every person) with 0:

```
df["By Day"] = df.groupby("Name").Comulative.diff().fillna(0)
```